# How to Calculate Train VS Test Adjusted R^2 for Regression

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, regression

I am a bit of confused regarding the calculation of adjusted R^2 for training and testing sets. What is the number of observations I should use when calculating the adjusted R^2 coefficient (*n*) for my training and testing datasets?

[This is the adjusted R2 formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YAtN4.jpg), where:

1. *n* represents the number of points (rows) in the data
2. *k* represents the number of independent regressors (columns excluding response variable)

My question is, what is the *n* used when calculating the adjusted R^2 on the training and testing data?

I used the formula from another question mentioned here (got the r2 from sklearn) function.

```py
adj_r2 = 1 - (1-r2)*(len(X)-1)/(len(X)-X.shape[1]-1)
```

whereby X is either X_train or X_test.

For `X_train` and `X_test`, `k` is the same but `n` differs. Take for example an 80-20 split resulting in 8 training rows and 2 testing rows. Do I use the respective train/test `n`'s when calculating adjusted R^2?

I feel that using a different `n` will lead to drastic differences in adjusted R^2 which leads to test R^2 being penalized much more.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should use the number of observations in each dataset respectively. That is: `n_train = len(X_train)` and `n_test = len(X_test)`.

And you are correct, this may lead to drastic changes in the adjusted R2 value, but only when your model is unstable. This is the whole idea behind splitting your data into training and testing datasets: you want your model to generalize well on previously unseen data. If your model is stable, it will have similar performance metrics across all datasets.

If your R2 coefficients vary a lot, this would be a sign that your model is overfitting on the training data. Your goal is to minimize that difference by tuning the hyperparameters of your model, transforming or dropping certain variables, etc.